# Change Color of Disabled Checkbox in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-checkbox

I have a checkbox in a listview in android. Checkboxes are there to indicate the item checked. I have set the checkbox disabled so that there wont be any events on clicking the checkbox. Now disabled checkbox tick mark is a very dull grey color tick. is there any way of changing the tick mark color of disabled checkbox in android?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bandroid%5D+checkbox+color

Answer (score 2):

You need separate images for your checkbox and that too for different states ... checked, not checked, disabled, clicked(transition between checked and not checked states).

after that you need to make a drawable.xml in you drawble folder and set it as the background of you checkbox.

Then only you can change the color of the checkbox on diff states.

Else, you need to go with the default theme.

Let me know if you need sample of what I said above. It seems complicated but quite easy.

[This page](http://android-support-akkilis.blogspot.in/2013/01/how-to-make-custom-drawable-background.html) tries to explain what I am saying.

Comment: sample code would be awesome. Thanks for your detailed response

Comment: @FahadAbidJanjua : added a link, please see if it helps. Let me know if you need more